# Problem on linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

Please tell me what did I do wrong with the problem(My professor said it's wrong and didn't clarify!)

> Suppose $V$ and $W$ are finite-dimensional vector spaces with $2\leq \dim V \leq \dim W$ . Show that $\{T\in L(V, W): T\text{ is not injective}\}$ is not a subspace of $L(V, W)$.

My solution: Let $T_1$ and $T_2$ be linear transformations from $V$ to $W$, such that $T_1$ takes only the vector $x$ to zero i.e. $T_1(x)=0,x=0$, and $T_2$ takes some vector $y$ to zero but not $x$ i.e. $T_2(y) =0$ but $T_2(x)$ not equal to zero, now $T_1$ and $T_2$ belong to $L(V, W)$ and are not injective and for the given set to be a subspace $T_1 +T_2$ must not be injective, i.e $(T_1+T_2)(z) =0$, by linearity $(T_1+T_2)(z) =0$ is $T_1(z) +T_2(z) =0$, now for this sum to be zero, the individual components must be zero, but $T_1(z) =0$ if and only if $z=x$ but then $T_2(z)$ won't be zero , thus $T_1+T_2$ will be injective thus proving what has been asked to prove. What did I do wrong?

Comment: I think your professor had in mind that $T_1(z)+T_2(z)=0$ does not imply that  each term of this sum is $0$.

Comment: Thanks to you, Bernard !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides the huge mistake of concluding $a+b=0\implies a=0$ or $b=0$ for $a,b$ vectors, your argument is far from being complete, though your basic idea seems to be correct.

You should have given a more specific construction for $T_1$ and $T_2$ to ensure injectivity of $T_1+T_2$, maybe using bases $v_1,\dots,v_n$ and $w_1,\dots,w_m$, noting that $n\le m$.